# Gitlab: Is it possible to auto assign new users to project groups

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab

We have a community install of Gitlab up and running using an omniauth strategy against our own private oAuth2 server.

**Question**: Is there was a way to auto assign all users to all Gitlab project groups automatically.

We're aware of this Rake command, which works via a cronjob or CLI nicely:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:import:all_users_to_all_groups RAILS_ENV=production
```

We've also worked out a set of API calls on our oAuth 2 server, such that each time a user logs into Gitlab via our server, their account is checked against all available groups and added to the groups.

This last method works well, but we want to make sure we are not entirely re-inventing the wheel here. As well, we would imagine if we had many groups, checking on each login would slow things down considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it in the best way possible (API) for your authentication method.

You could do this easily with LDAP / AD integration in GitLab Enterprise Edition, with the built-in group sync.

We're always looking into improving GitLab. What would make GitLab more convenient in this regard for you? Feel free to submit your ideas on feedback.gitlab.com.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation on our methods. I'm considering using LDAP as alternative. Need to get a custom LDAP server with MysQL backend going first. Unfortunately the Enterprise edition is out of our reach.

Comment: @OutofControl I don't want to start a sales conversation here, but depending on your situation GitLab EE is less than $2 p/m per dev.